# Validation Rule IsChanged

Tags: validation-rule

I have this validation formula, which is not firing when I provide a `Contract_End_Date__c` prior to today's date. Otherwise for any future date it is working as expected.

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Status_Category__c ,"In Effect"),
    ISCHANGED(Contract_End_Date__c),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status__c ,"Extended")),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status__c ,"Preponed"))
)
```

Comment: Are there any triggers or flows running for that object that might be doing something to the date or the status and category?

Comment: Above validation rule criteria only check the `Contract_End_Date__c` is changed or not only not like the given date value is past date value or future. So May be can you please add another one condition as `Contract_End_Date__c > TODAY()` into that same `AND` block and Check again?

Comment: @Raj Adding another condition into an `AND()` will _never_ make it return `true` if it is currently returning `false` (as is the case here).

Comment: Validation rule cannot be bypassed by any trigger or flow

Comment: That wasn't the point that fred was getting at. Triggers and flows can run before your validation rule is checked. If you have a before update trigger that says "if this date is in the past, undo that change", then `ISCHANGED(Contract_End_Date__c)` would see that there is no change. I suppose this isn't really a question about _if_ you have a flow/trigger that's modifying your date so much as it is a statement that _you must currently have such a flow/trigger for you to observe the results you're seeing_. You'll need to either accept that behavior, or find that flow/trigger and change it.

Comment: About the only other possibility here is that `Contract_End_Date__c` is a formula field on `Opportunity` that is just a copy of the `CloseDate` field, which has some automatic, unchangeable logic tied to it that causes future dates to be changed to today's date when the Opp moves to a closed-won stage (but you can't use `ISCHANGED()` on a formula field, and that would cause future dates to creep past your validation rule, which is the opposite of what you say is happening).